# Working Plone contact form into main_template.pt

Tags: python, plone

I'm trying to work the contact form that is baked into plone into my site's main_template. I'm doing so to make the functionality present in "get in touch" nav button on [this site](http://headscape.co.uk) work in a plone setting. My approach to doing this was by slightly reworking [contact-info.cpt](http://pastebin.com/CAWYawV5) to make it a macro and using that macro within main_template.pt. I get a LocationError when I try to view any page on my site, unless i remove the `tal:define="errors options/state/getErrors"` line from contact-info.cpt.

[This](http://pastebin.com/XdrKZcdG) is the error I get with that line in the code. If I remove that line the page will render and actually looks exactly the way I want it to, but will error out upon submitting the form. [This](http://pastebin.com/r6EfsJPb) is the error in that situation. I'm basically stumped in both situations and would appreciate any advice.

UPDATE (the solution I used):

Just wanted to post an update with how I actually got this to work. The information from Martijn Pieters was very helpful in understanding why it wasn't working, but I really wasn't in the position to getting working from there. I ended up falling back on jQuery to get this working in the site_actions and in my custom dropdown. I wrapped the contents of the form between the `<metal:main>` tags with a div that i gave the simple id "contact-info". Then in the main template, I also entered a generic div with a simple id of "load-area". The last piece of the puzzle was to change my contact.js file to be contact.js.pt and enter these 3 lines:

```
  <tal:block define="portal_url context/@@plone_portal_state/portal_url">
  jq('#load-area').load('<span tal:replace="portal_url"></span>/contact-info #contact-info');
  </tal:block>
```

Thought I should post this incase it can help anyone else out later.

Comment: Did you copy contact-info.cpt.metadata file to your theme also?

Comment: Yes I did, I was actually using your tutorial as the resource to know which files were involved with the contact form.

Comment: I think Plone somehow thinks contact-info is not controlled page template, but normal page template, because "state" is missing from the template global variables. But I cannot guess the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a Controller Page Template (`.cpt`) as a macro, unchanged.

First of all, a Controller Python Script expects a few parameters in it's "environment" (the `options/state` structure is one of these) that you don't have present when re-using it's TAL statements. You'll have to rework the template to not rely on those parts.

Secondly, this is a HTML form, and a form requires a target to send it's data to. In a Controller Page Template this is controlled with the `.metadata` file, you'll have to set it's target explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://svn.quintagroup.com/products/quintagroup.portlet.pfg/trunk/

seems not to be supported though

in combination with PloneFormGen you can create a contact-form and show it as a portlet